# Specify number of lines for href inside span tag

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, styles

I have a `<span>` tag, `.lastMessageLink`, with an `<a>` inside it, `.lastMessageText`. The text that could be put in `.lastMessageText` could be as short as a couple characters, or as long as a paragraph, but I want to display maximum 4 lines of text.

The current styling I have, which is not working, is this:

```
.lastMessageLink {
    line-height: 1em;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    max-height: 4em;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.lastMessageText {
    color: black;
    word-wrap: break-word;
}
```

And here is the HTML:

```
<span class="lastMessageLink">
    <a id="undefined" class="lastMessageText" title="now i need a really really long message so that i can test this whole multiple lines thing which is gonna be a problem and a trickier problem than we had initially thought. it's interesting because you'd think a couple css styles would be enough, but we might have to go by characters" href="#conversation:cid=10714&amp;mid=10735">
        now i need a really really long message so that i can test this whole multiple lines thing which is gonna be a problem and a trickier problem than we had initially thought. it's interesting because you'd think a couple css styles would be enough, but we might have to go by characters
    </a>
</span>
```

I have looked at [HTML/CSS: Specify number of lines inside <span>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4748798/html-css-specify-number-of-lines-inside-span), [Limit text length to n lines using CSS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3922739/limit-text-length-to-n-lines-using-css), [Using CSS text-overflow to vary the number of lines of text within an element of a set height](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1067166/using-css-text-overflow-to-vary-the-number-of-lines-of-text-within-an-element-of), and [How to set element height for a fixed number of lines of text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3675623/how-to-set-element-height-for-a-fixed-number-of-lines-of-text).

I am open to solutions that use jQuery or Javascript as I have been unable to make progress solely with CSS.

Comment: Well `<span>` tags are (without contrary styling) **inline** elements, and therefore it doesn't make sense to limit their dimensions. You can override that and make them `display: block` or `display: inline-block` and then use a `max-height` setting to limit the height.  HTML/CSS don't really understand the concept of "line of text" too well.

Comment: can you post the HTML part? when you say it's not working, how is it not working (doesn't restrict # of lines, overflows, doesn't show, etc)

Comment: @Pointy guess you mean you can override that and make them `display:block`

Comment: It doesn't restrict the number of lines. The whole thing shows up. I'll post the HTML.

Comment: @norabora oh you also have to set `overflow: hidden`

Comment: Don't you prefer to use a `<textarea>`?

Comment: @Pointy I did set `overflow:hidden` on the span tag

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change `<span>` to `<div>` and that should do the trick I think

Comment: because div is a block level element which allows the max-height rule to be obeyed, the sap you have at the moment is an inline element which you can't set a height on, if for some reason you need it to stay a span use the css property display: block on it

Answer (score 2):

Research on the web as well as some [former stack overflow questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8068552/is-it-possible-to-have-text-overflow-ellipsis-without-white-space-nowrap) ([here also](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6572330/is-it-possible-to-use-text-overflowellipsis-on-multiline-text)) indicate that unless `white-space: nowrap` is set, `ellipsis` does not work. That, of course, means *it only works with one line of text*.

Some possible JQuery plugins to compensate:

**Three Dots**
http://tpgblog.com/2009/12/21/threedots-the-jquery-ellipsis-plugin/

**jQuery Text Overflow**
http://www.bramstein.com/projects/text-overflow/

**Auto Ellipsis**
http://pvdspek.github.com/jquery.autoellipsis/